# Any way/API to get the files modified through merge requests in a given period of time

Tags: git, shell, github, gitlab, gitlab-api

I am looking for way or API to list the files that are updated/modified through merge requests only in a given period of time(date range).

I had very hard time to find a solution, anyhelp?